# How to style Google Custom Search Engine so that it doesn't display as a block element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to include Google Custom Search Engine in my navigation bar after the menu items, on the same line. However, Google Custom Search Engine displays as a block by default and puts itself in a new line below the menu items. I have tried to put it inside a `<span>` and styled it `display:inline;` `display:inline-block;` `float:right;` among many others to no avail. I have learnt that `<gcse:searchbox-only></gcse:searchbox-only>` is what makes it display as a block element but on removing it the search box doesn't display at all.

NOTE: In the below snippet, html `<script>` tags are to enclose the javascript above them. `<gcse:searchbox-only></gcse:searchbox-only>` is after the closing `</script>` tag. The code editor needed html and javascript to be typed into different blocks.

```js
  (function() {
    var cx = '006011447236506019758:t1r90lozvsc';
    var gcse = document.createElement('script');
    gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
    gcse.async = true;
    gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
        '//cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
  })();
```

```html
<script>
</script>
<gcse:searchbox-only></gcse:searchbox-only>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always use css to style the div by using its id.

For Example:

```html
<style>
/* New Code Here! */
div#___gcse_0 {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
}
</style>

<script>
(function() {
    var cx = '006011447236506019758:t1r90lozvsc';
    var gcse = document.createElement('script');
    gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
    gcse.async = true;
    gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
        '//cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
  })();
</script>
<gcse:searchbox-only></gcse:searchbox-only>
<div style="display: inline-block">This is after the search</div>
<div style="display: inline-block">This is after the text</div>
```

This creates a 200px search bar.

EDIT: Showed an example in a working copy.

Comment: doesn't help. it still display as a block and takes up a whole new line by itself no matter what width you set.

Comment: Works now. Thank you. :)

Comment: To anybody facing the same problem you have to set the styles `!important`.